# Google Search Console Validation Failing

Tags: seo, google-search

all

I'm attempting to validate my client's website with their Google Search Console account. I've confirmed that the meta tag for site verification is in the head of the site, and that it correctly corresponds with the string that Google is looking for in the Search Console. However, validation repeatedly fails with the message that the meta tag is not in the head of the document. I've also attempted to validate using the client's Google Analytics account, which also returns the error that the async code is not in the head of the document, even though I've confirmed that it is.

Quite puzzled by this, as it's the same process I've used on many other sites, including my own, without ever having issue. Any input in appreciated.

The site in question is http://reasonableandcaringdental.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...And, it was programmer error :) There was an open tag in the head prior to the Google meta tag, preventing an accurate crawl of the site.